# Amazon Athena SQL query doesn't yield required result - percentage of total

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, presto, amazon-athena

I tried this in Athena but I believe it is a proper SQL query as well.

I have a table with `channel` column and I want to get "per month the share of channel equals 1 from the total of channel". So I thought about using conditional statement and putting 1 when it is 1 and 0 otherwise and then summing it which is like counting occurrences of 1 divided by total count of a month.
But it just gives me zeros and not the actual share. What is wrong with the query?

```sql
select
  month,
  count(), 
  sum(case when channel = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count()
from table
where bla bla 
group by 1 order by 1;
```

Comment: You might need to use a *nested query* in this case:  the "inner" query produces the raw numbers, and the "outer" query produces summaries.  Or, you might need to `JOIN` the results produced by two or more subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be integer division.  Here are two approaches:

```
Select month , count(*), sum(case when channel = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) / count(*)
from table
where bla bla
group by 1
order by 1;

Select month , count(), avg(case when channel = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end)
from table
where bla bla
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Note that `avg()` is a simpler way to do this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

While other proposed solutions work perfectly, I wanted to put a less verbose alternative out there:

```
select month, count(), count_if(channel=1)*1./count()
from table where
...
```